# How to use lapply to put elements of a list into different data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have a list of dataframes called db; each data frame has its name.
I use:

```
lapply(names(db),
       function(x)write.csv(db[x],
                            file =paste0(x,'.csv')))
```

to extract the d.frames and save them into csv files.
Now i'm trying to extact from the list the dataframes and create different dataframes with this command:

```
lapply(names(db),
       function(x)as.data.frame(db[x]))
```

But it does not store any data frame into the workspace , how can I store each df with different names into the workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We extract the `list` elements with `[[`

```
lapply(names(db), function(x) write.csv(db[[x]],
        file =paste0(x,'.csv'), row.names=FALSE, quote= FALSE))
```

as `db[x]` is still a `list` of `data.frame` with `length` 1.

If these are big datasets, the `fwrite` function from `data.table` would be more efficient

```
library(data.table)
lapply(names(db), function(x) fwrite(db[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".csv")))
```

---

Just to illustrate the issue,

```
set.seed(24)
db <- setNames(lapply(1:3, function(i) as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 
                             5*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))), paste0("df", 1:3))
```

The difference between the OP's approach and the `[[` is in the OP's approach it will `write` the files with column names that have a prefix from the `names` of 'db' whereas the `[[` will not have any such problem.

---

Regarding the second problem, that is creating multiple objects in the global environment, we can use `list2env` directly on the 'db'

```
list2env(db, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

But, this is not recommended as it most of the operations can be done within the `list` itself.

```
df1
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  3  9  6  9
#2  3  3  4  2
#3  7  7  7  1
#4  5  8  7  5
#5  6  3  3  2
```