# For loops versus lapply

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have written the following loop:

```
library(data.table)

for(i in seq_along(df)){
  fwrite(df[[i]], paste('Name_', as.character(i), '.csv', sep = ''))
}

# df is a list. Each element of the list is a data.frame
```

I save each element of `df` - a list of `data.frame` - as a `.csv`, assigning them different names according to `i`. 
How do I translate that loop into `lapply` syntax? I have tried (unsuccessfully):

```
lapply(df, function(x) fwrite(x, paste('Name_', as.character(x), '.csv', sep = '')))
```

and (worse as x is not specified):

```
lapply(df, fwrite, paste('Name_', as.character(x), '.csv', sep = ''))
```

Comment: Just like in `for` loop, loop through the sequence i,.e `lapply(seq_along(df), function(i) fwrite(df[[i]], paste('Name_', x, '.csv', sep='')))`

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563164/how-to-use-lapply-to-put-elements-of-a-list-into-different-data-frames)

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much! I knew I was missing something.

Comment: You are only interested in a side effect (creating a file). A `for` loop is more appropriate for this than `lapply`.